# How to Backup my files (Mails, Contacts, Account Information) in Thunderbird from Flatpak?

Tags: backup, email, thunderbird, flatpak

How can I backup my data so I can restore my mails and such if I have to move to another computer or if my machine breaks? Information I found seems to not work for Thunderbird from Flathub, I dont have a `.thunderbird` directory in my `~/`. When I go to *"Help -> Troubleshooting Information"* and click the open profile folder button, nothing happens.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you remember to look in `~/.cache/thunderbird/` ?

Comment: That directory does not exist. `.cache` yes, but not the thunderbird subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

First, to find your existing profile, go back to *"Help -> Troubleshooting Information"* but instead of clicking *"Open Directory"* scroll down & find the *"about:profiles"* link. Click that and you will be shown the path to your existing profiles. Mine was located in `~/.var/app/org.mozilla.Thunderbird/cache/thunderbird`.

Second, Thunderbird still tries to put files in `~/.thunderbird` but doesn't have access to your home directory. I had to fix this in order to move my existing profile into my new flatpak Thunderbird profile.

To give Thunderbird permission to access the ~/.thunderbird directory, enter the following command into a terminal (replacing "[your user directory]" with the appropriate string)

`sudo flatpak override org.mozilla.Thunderbird --filesystem=/home/[your user directory]/.thunderbird/`

After that, Thunderbird will be able to resume using the `~/.thunderbird` directory and the *"Open Directory"* button should work again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly I cannot try this because I am not using Thunderbird anymore at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, if you're using [flatseal](https://github.com/tchx84/flatseal), which is a permission utility for flatpak, select you app, and just scroll down on the right pane until you find **FIle System**, and toggle **All system files**:
[image: flatseal toggel file system]